# Magento 1.8.1.0 - Applying patch 6788 failed

Tags: magento-1.8, patches

I'am trying to apply patch 6788 to my magento 1.8.1.0 installation.

I've uploaded the patch to the root of the magento installation.

When I run the patch it gives me the following output:

Executed command: `./PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.8.1.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-59-27.sh`

Output:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file .htaccess
checking file .htaccess.sample
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
8 out of 8 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 297 (offset 3 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 154 (offset 23 lines).
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
4 out of 4 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
Hunk #5 succeeded at 381 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #6 succeeded at 389 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #7 succeeded at 756 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #8 succeeded at 799 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #9 succeeded at 830 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #10 succeeded at 840 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #11 succeeded at 1025 (offset -2 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 168 with fuzz 1 (offset 29 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Zend/Soap/Server.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Exception.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file app/code/core/Zend/Xml/Security.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Response.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
checking file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
checking file cron.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file errors/processor.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
The next patch would create the file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php,
which already exists!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
```

Comment: This issue is resolve Frank Groot?